# C# Getting the IP Address of the client which the UDP server socket received data from

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp

I have a very strange problem. I'm not able to find the IP Address of the client which my server receives data from. Below is my UDP Listener class.

The **IPPacketInformation** does not contain the IP. The *clientEndPoint* which I reference in my *EndReceiveMessageFrom* does neither.

When I

```
Console.Writeline(((IPEndPoint)clientEndPoint).Address);
```

I get the IP Address of the server. I have the server hosted on my own machine so I get my own IP Address. When I try to access clientEndPoint.remoteEndPoint it throws an error because the socket isn't connected (due to being UDP).

So basically, a client from an external IP is able to send data, but I can't answer the client since I'm not able to retrieve it's IP. Any help is appreciated!

```
public class UdpListener
{
    private Socket s;
    public byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[2048];

    public UdpListener()
    {
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 36200));
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            s.BeginReceiveMessageFrom(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEndPoint, Recv, s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void Recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket receiveSocket = (Socket)res.AsyncState;

            EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            IPPacketInformation packetInfo;
            SocketFlags flags = SocketFlags.None;
            int udpMessageLength = receiveSocket.EndReceiveMessageFrom(res, ref flags, ref clientEndPoint, out packetInfo);
            byte[] udpMessage = new byte[udpMessageLength];
            Array.Copy(ReceiveBuffer, udpMessage, udpMessageLength);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0} bytes received from {1} to {2}",
                ReceiveBuffer,
                clientEndPoint,
                packetInfo.Address
            );

            EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ((IPEndPoint)receiveSocket.LocalEndPoint).Port);
            s.BeginReceiveMessageFrom(ReceiveBuffer, 0, ReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEndPoint, Recv, s);

            //Process data
            RaiseDataReceived(new ReceivedDataArgs(packetInfo.Address, ((IPEndPoint)clientEndPoint).Port, udpMessage));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    public delegate void DataReceived(ReceivedDataArgs args);

    public event DataReceived DataReceivedEvent;

    private void RaiseDataReceived(ReceivedDataArgs args)
    {
        DataReceivedEvent?.Invoke(args);
    }
}
```

I've tried to disable my firewall but that does not help. I've also done Port Forwarding on my router thus I can receive data from external clients.

**EDIT** to clarify the problem:

Server hosted on my machine behind a NAT with public IP 214.214.214.214.

The client is another machine, behind another NAT with public IP 910.910.910.910.

The client sends a message to the server, server receives it and able to read the content. When server get the IPEndPoint of the client, the displayed IP is 214.214.214.214 (IP of the server, **not the Client**)

**EDIT** Maybe I should say that I wasn't able to receive messages from clients on external networks until I ordered a "Dynamic IP" from my ISP. Still can't get the public IP of the source.

**EDIT** When using Wireshark and sniff a packet sent from external client to my server I can see it's the wrong src IP as well. In the picture below the src IP is my server IP and not the IP of the client that sent the data.

[image]

Comment: Why are you listening to Port Zero? IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

Comment: Im listening on port 36200. If you mean the remoteEndPoint or clientEndPoint port 0 the endPoint get's overridden whenever a message is received

Comment: Have you considered using [UdpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: I have tried that. Same result. I've also tried Receive, ReceiveFrom, ReceiveAsync.

Comment: Are you sure the ovderriding of the port number is working.  I never heard of a port number changing once the Listener is started.

Comment: I reference the EndPoint in BeginReceiveMessageFrom and EndReceiveMessageFrom. These methods ensure the right port of the Client but when accessing the Address it's my own (the server) public IP. When running multiple clients on localhost the port for each message is correct.

Comment: I´m not sure I really understand the problem, your code works fine here (client and listener on same machine, both clientEndPoint and packetInfo contain correct data). Does it only fail using a separate client machine?

Comment: It works completely fine when running on same machine. The problem is, when you run a client on another machine + behind another router - I dont receive the client IP but my own IP on the server side

Comment: Edited my post to clarify the problem

Comment: Were you able to figure out what happens when you create a `UdpClient(IPEndpoint)` bound to an endpoint and then use `Receive(IPAddress.Any, 0)`? MSDN docs do not really explain what happens when you bind a UdpClient and then what happens when you hit the `Receive` method. Why are there 2 IPEndpoints to specify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After several days of reading everything I possibly could on routers, network and writing different examples of *Receive, ReceiveFrom, ReceiveMessageFrom, BeginReceive, BeginReceiveFrom, BeginReceiveMessageFrom*, and *ReceiveAsync* - I've solved my issue.

**I changed my router.** I can now get the source IP of the external client using a very old router. The router I was using before was a new Docsis 3.1.

Why it works with an old router, I don't know, but for some reason, the Docsis 3.1 changed the source IP to its own IP before letting the UDP message to my machine.

Comment: I feel your pain. There is a surprising limited amount of information about what actually happens with packets when using C# sockets. Different answers recommend "multicasting" for communication but after days of troubleshooting you will learn that not all routers support igmp packet resolution. Also, what actually happens when you create a `UdpClient`, like what actual network interface it is bound on. Or when to use Receive vs. BeginReceive.

Answer (score 1):

With using the `UdpClient` class you can actually retrieve the remote endpoint when receiving a message.

I have used a solution like the following to solve this task:

```
public void StartServer()
{
    var udpServer = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ConnectionInformation.DETECTION_PORT));
    udpServer.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(detectionCallback), udpServer);
}

private void detectionCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var client = (ar.AsyncState as UdpClient);
    if (client.Client == null) return;

    var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ConnectionInformation.DETECTION_PORT);
    var bytes = client.EndReceive(ar, ref endPoint);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Detection request from: {endPoint}");
}
```

Comment: Tried this example with server public IP: 214.214.214.214 and Client public IP: 910.910.910.910. When sending a message from client to server, the endPoint printed on the server contains "214.214.214.214:57650" and not "910.910.910.910:57650"

Comment: Client public IP: 910.910.910.910?  How can that be the client IP?  It's not a valid IP address.

Comment: It's an example since I won't provide my own IP

Comment: Unfortunately this is a naive solution. Creating a UdpClient on `IPAddress.Any` will not provide the correct functionality if it chooses the wrong network interface. Some computers may have USB wifi dongles, or have multiple networking interfaces.